# How to integrate the differential equation $\frac{dx}{dt}=a(x-c)^2-bx^2$ given initial condition

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential equation

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=a(x-c)^2-bx^2$$

where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are constants and the initial condition is $x=0$ for $t=0$. .

How would I go about solving this?

I have tried separation of variables followed by integration by substitution, but I cannot seem to get the answer below,

$$x=\frac{c}{1+(\frac{b}{a})^\frac{1}{2}\coth ((ab)^\frac{1}{2}ct)}$$

Any help would be much appreciated.

The question is adapted from the part 3 of [this paper](http://terpconnect.umd.edu/~ggoldenb/Sail3.pdf).

Comment: $${dx\over dx^2+ex+f}={dx\over d(x-p)(x-q)}$$

Comment: You should examine those constants a bit more carefully.  If $a = b$, the equation changes substantially.  If $ b < 0$, matching the initial condition is ... complicated.  So, can these constants (individually) be negative? zero? positive?  Is it guaranteed that they are unequal in pairs? that one is definitely greater than (or greater than or equal to) another?

Comment: You can plug this into [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%3Da*%28y%28x%29-c%29%5E2-b*y%28x%29%5E2+solve+diff+eq). This results in some leads: Find the link on Riccati Differential Equations.

Comment: Also, the solution you've written is not a solution to the given equation.  Is there a typo'?

Answer (score 1):

For the case when $a=b,$ the right hand side simplifies into a linear function in $x,$ which you can do.

For when $a\ne b,$ the interesting part is integrating a differential whose coefficient is the reciprocal of the square root of a quadratic; this is still doable, but we need to know what form the quadratic takes. In particular, when $a\ne b,$ we may make it monic by factoring out the leading coefficient and completing the squares, to get a constant multiple of $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(x-\frac{ac}{a-b}\right)^2-\frac{abc^2}{(a-b)^2}}}.$$ Thus, how one would now proceed depends on the sign of $ab.$ If $ab<0,$ then we would use the substitution $$\sinh y=C(a,b,c)\times \left(x-\frac{ac}{a-b}\right),$$ where $C,$ as indicated, is a constant depending on $a,b,c,$ not necessarily all. For the case when $ac>0,$ we would use a sine instead of the hyperbolic sine. The rest is just computation.

Answer (score 0):

The ode may be relatively straightforward to integrate; care needs to be taken in handling initial condition, though.

Use the variable change

$$y(t)=\frac{(a-b)x(t)-ac}{\sqrt{ab}c}, \>\>\>\>\>y(0)=-\sqrt{\frac ab}\tag{1}$$

to rewrite the original ode

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=a(x-c)^2-bx^2$$

in the convenient form below

$$\frac{dy}{y^2-1}=\sqrt{ab}c\>dt$$

Then, integrate with the proper limits

$$\int_{y(0)}^{y(t)} \frac{dy}{y^2-1}=\sqrt{ab}c\int_0^t d\tau$$

to get

$$\coth^{-1}y(0)-\coth^{-1}y(t) = \sqrt{ab}c\>t$$

Utilize the identity below and substitute (1)

$$\coth^{-1} p -\coth^{-1} q = \coth^{-1} \left( \frac{1-pq}{ p - q} \right)$$

to obtain

$$\sqrt{\frac ab}\left( \frac cx-1\right) = \coth(\sqrt{ab}ct)$$

Then, rearrange to cast it in the desired form,

$$x(t)=\frac{c}{1+(\frac{b}{a})^\frac{1}{2}\coth ((ab)^\frac{1}{2}ct)}$$